# Specializing a template for std tuple without requiring users to do remove_cvref

Tags: c++, templates, c++20

As you maybe know since C++ does not support list of types except in special cases most people just use tuple as ugly list of types.
So for example to check if some list contains only fp numbers one might do this:

```
template <typename T>
struct AllFp {};
template <typename... T>
struct AllFp<std::tuple<T...>> {
  static constexpr bool value =
      (std::is_floating_point_v<std::remove_cvref_t<T>> && ...);
};
```

While this might seem to work, it actually does not if users pass const std::tuple or reference to tuple.

```
#include<type_traits>
#include<tuple>

template <typename T>
struct AllFp {};
template <typename... T>
struct AllFp<std::tuple<T...>> {
  static constexpr bool value =
      (std::is_floating_point_v<std::remove_cvref_t<T>> && ...);
};
int main(){
    static_assert(!AllFp<std::tuple<float, int, float>>::value);
    static_assert(AllFp<std::tuple<float, long double, float>>::value);
    // requires std::remove_cvref_t
    //static_assert(AllFp<const std::tuple<float, long double, float>>::value);
    //static_assert(AllFp<std::tuple<float, long double, float>&>::value);
}
```

Is there a way I can write the template so that "users"(people using AllFp) do not need to clean the type of tuple they pass?

note:tagging C++20 since I am ok with concepts solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [Boost.Mp11](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/mp11/doc/html/mp11.html), this is a short one-liner (as always):

```
template <typename L>
using AllFp = mp_all_of<std::remove_cvref_t<L>, std::is_floating_point>;
```

Note that [`std::remove_cvref_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_cvref) is actually C++20. For earlier standards, you can just do `std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<L>>` or just `std::decay_t<L>` for brevity.

---

With corrected predicate:

```
template <typename T>
using decays_to_fp = std::is_floating_point<std::remove_cvref_t<T>>;

template <typename L>
using AllFp = mp_all_of<std::remove_cvref_t<L>, decays_to_fp>;
```

Or:

```
template <typename L>
using AllFp = mp_all_of_q<std::remove_cvref_t<L>,
    mp_compose<std::remove_cvref_t, std::is_floating_point>>;
```

Comment: I think your code does not match my original example, eg. for std::tuple<float&, double&> I am not saying that my decision to remove inner qualifiers is good, I guess it depends on usage/convention, just saying.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl Oh, sure. Just change the predicate. The point is that AllFp should just strip the qualifiers if it doesn't care about them.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is an additional level of indirection. Rename your primary template, and specialization, from `AllFp` to `AllFp_Impl`. Then make `AllFp` an alias template that does the job of removing the cvref qualifications from the `tuple` itself:

```
template <typename T>
using AllFp = AllFp_Impl<std::remove_cvref_t<T>>;
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/zEwceY).

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a sort of self-inheritance.

I mean: you can add following specializations

```
template <typename T>
struct AllFp<T const> : public AllFp<T>
 { };

template <typename T>
struct AllFp<T&> : public AllFp<T>
 { };
```

The following is a full compiling (no error from `static_assert()`) example that uses only `std::remove_cv_t`

```
#include<type_traits>
#include<tuple>

template <typename T>
struct AllFp {};

template <typename T>
struct AllFp<T const> : public AllFp<T>
 { };

template <typename T>
struct AllFp<T&> : public AllFp<T>
 { };

template <typename... T>
struct AllFp<std::tuple<T...>> {
  static constexpr bool value =
      (std::is_floating_point_v<std::remove_cv_t<T>> && ...);
};

int main(){
    static_assert(!AllFp<std::tuple<float, int, float>>::value);
    static_assert(AllFp<std::tuple<float, long double, float>>::value);
    static_assert(AllFp<const std::tuple<float, long double, float>>::value);
    static_assert(AllFp<std::tuple<float, long double, float>&>::value);
}
```